# how to get table updated only once after page reloaded

Tags: php, href, insert-update

i made an application where user have some points(like stackoverflow reputation), if someone want to see other answer then his 2 point will be deducted.
so what actually did i passed que_id and uniq_id into url or link, and on the basis of that value i updated his POINTS with -2.
see my url is:

```
<a href='marks.php?que_id =$que_id && uniq_id = $uniq_val' target='_blank' onclick='p_alert()'>Answers</a>
```

and update table as:

```
$n_points = $o_points - $cut_points;
$res1 = "update $tab set points = '$n_points' where uniq = '$uniq_val'";
```

its working fine but problem occurs when page get reloaded and the points cutting simultaneously with each refresh.

so what i do for overcome this(**expect header() redirection**), any idea suggestion would be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As you've rightly said, you should do a redirect at that point to take the URL away from there. So

```
header('Location: www.yoursite.com/new-page');
exit();
```

You can also track the previous clicks by IP or if a user is logged in when clicking by their unique id before performing the update query. To do this you would need to create a separate table with a user ID and content ID for tracking the rep assignment. Then you could do a `SELECT` to see if content has been rated based on a content id and user id and if not, `UPDATE` the rep, and `INSERT` a record into the new tracking table so the next time they go to the URL, it won't add the rep

Comment: In that instance you will need a table to track points assigned by a user to another user based on the content you're giving reputation from. So you would need the content id and user id, then do a select on that table to see if the user has already given rep

Comment: Updated my answer to include this

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist that the user has payed to see that answer.

So you just deducted if the user did not see the answer yet.

Create a user_answer_view with the userId and the answer.

You can do what you think like that:

```
header('Location: marks.com/page.php');
```

But it is unsafe. Because the user can set the url with ids and the problem will persist.